# UWP StreamSocket client not receiving response after larger data transfer

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, uwp

I have a WPF 'server' app using a socket, with a UWP 'client' app using StreamSocket. I can transfer small amounts of data fine, but if I try and send a 288kb file, the file is received fine by the WPF app but the UWP app never receives the response.

WPF code:
In the ReadCallback method, the content is sent in the format of command;printername{data}. The data is all received fine but the Send method called before processing the data is not received.

```
public void Start()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(x =>x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
                var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Settings.Default.PrintPort);

                listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                    listener.Listen(100);
                    IsRunning = true;
                    while (true)
                    {

                        // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                        AllDone.Reset();

                        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                        listener.BeginAccept(
                            AcceptCallback,
                            listener);

                        // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                        AllDone.WaitOne();


                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            });
        }
public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if(!IsRunning) return;

            // Signal the main thread to continue.  
            AllDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request. 
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject {WorkSocket = handler};
            handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                ReadCallback, state);
        }
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
                // from the asynchronous state object.  
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

                // Read data from the client socket.   
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
                    state.Sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
                    // more data.  
                    var content = state.Sb.ToString();


                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        content = content.Remove(content.IndexOf("<EOF>"));
                        if (content.StartsWith("PrintFile"))
                        {
                            if (!content.Contains("{"))
                            {
                                Send(handler, "false");
                                return;
                            }
                            var parts = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf('{')).Split(';');
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parts[1]))
                            {
                                Send(handler, "false");
                                return;
                            }
                            // This send never gets received
                            Send(handler, "true");
                            //But the file is printed
                            var base64 = content.Substring(content.IndexOf('{') + 1);
                            base64 = base64.Remove(base64.LastIndexOf('}'));
                            var doc = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
                            doc.PrintSettings.PrinterName = parts[1];
                            doc.Print();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Not all data received. Get more.  
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            ReadCallback, state);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                //Ignore
            }
        }

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                SendCallback, handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

UWP Code:

```
 public bool PrintFlle(string printer, string base64)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = Send($"PrintFile;{printer}{{{base64}}}<EOF>").Result;
                return bool.TryParse(result, out var b) && b;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                socket.Dispose();
            }
        }



        private async Task<string> Send(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = new StreamSocket();

                await socket.ConnectAsync(HostName, App.LocalSettings.Values["PrintPort"] as string);
                using (Stream outputStream = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(input);
                        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }

                using (Stream inputStream = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
                    {
                        var output = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                        socket.Dispose();
                        return output;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                socket.Dispose();
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Start by using a sniffer like wireshark ro fiddler and see what you are actually sending.  Make sure you are sending "<EOF>".  Make sure you are not encoding the "<EOF>"  if you are sending a base 64 string.  Make sure if you are using ASCII Encoding that the encoding isn't remove characters so your byte counts are wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The base64 is being sent to the server fine and it printing off, its just the response that's not being picked up by the client

Comment: The send method is closing the connection so you will not get a response.  The response should be coming back on same connection that was used to send message.

Comment: I am getting a response if its a small amount of data being sent.

Comment: If it is a size issue then the printer has limits set and is failing if you send a large file.  Or there is a character in the data that is causing the file to get rejected.  Are you getting any error messages on the printer?  Usually error like this are due to using wrong printer driver.  Possible using a PS instead of a PCL driver.

Comment: The file is being received and printing out fine. The UWP client doesnt get past the flushasync in the below part of code
~~~
using (Stream outputStream = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(input);
                        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
~~~

Comment: The SendCallback() is closing connection so you never will receive.